# Do I need a Bitcoin full node in order to use BTC RPC Explorer?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockexplorer, pruning

I'm thinking of using https://github.com/janoside/btc-rpc-explorer as my json explorer, but I run a pruned bitcoin node. Will this cause issues when running btc-rpc-explorer if I wanted to query old data? And if so what is the appropriate pruned node amount to access 1-2 years of blockchain history?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this cause issues when running btc-rpc-explorer if I wanted to query old data?

Yes, as [it requires `txindex`](https://github.com/janoside/btc-rpc-explorer#prerequisites).

> And if so what is the appropriate pruned node amount to access 1-2 years of blockchain history?

`txindex` is currently only supported without pruning, so you need to have a non-pruned `bitcoind` to use `btc-rpc-explorer`.